# Internal laptop screen is not avaiable after lid close event, instead multiple times attached

Tags: gnome, display, screen, fedora, lid

I am running Ubuntu 17 on a Surface Pro 4. I had the same issue with Fedora 27. Both running gnome as desktop.

I have a external (DELL) monitor connected to my surface 4. When I close the lid, internal and external display turn off. After opening the lid, only the external screen works, the internal screen stays black and is even not listed under devices anymore:

[image]

Any idea how to solve this issue? How can I get my internal display to be used again after lid close event? Also I want to report it on Bugzilla, but what is the right category? New -> Core and then? gnome‑desktop?